# Array exponentiation

Tags: ruby

I have a string, for example

```
a = 'Thank you for your answer'
```

and I need to  get the length of each word from the string and raising them to a power next word, for this example:

```
result = ((((5**3)**3)**4)**6)
```

How do I do that?

Comment: I think your `((((5**3)**3)**4)**5)` is `((((5**3)**3)**4)**6)` instead (the last number is `6`)

Comment: I doubt that anyone will give an answer that improves on @太's, but I would encourage you to wait longer, in future, before awarding the greenie. A quick selection may discourage other, possibly better, possibly just interesting, answers, and imo is a discourtesy to others who may still be preparing their answers. There's no rush, so why not wait awhile? Many here wait at least a couple of hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`inject` will do:

```
s = 'Thank you for your answer'

s.split(/\s+/)
# => ["Thank", "you", "for", "your", "answer"]

s.split(/\s+/).map{|w| w.length}
# => [5, 3, 3, 4, 6]

s.split(/\s+/).map{|w| w.length}.inject(:**)
# => 9495567745759798747473242269561957154220965833619944966279779990829008230644811159033118931771413600093027632988162967109246892505325376987457275390625

((((5**3)**3)**4)**6)
# => 9495567745759798747473242269561957154220965833619944966279779990829008230644811159033118931771413600093027632988162967109246892505325376987457275390625
```

Comment: A couple of small points: 1. `s.split(/\s+/)` is the same as `s.split`. 2. `map { |w| w.length }` can be simplified to `map(&:length)`.